# set up Redux store listener in different screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Im pretty new to redux therefore please excuse me if my explanation is a little bit sloppy: I have a complex react native app using the redux store but also firebase stuff and react navigation. Im declaring my redux store in a parents js file which wraps all other screens with a navigator, declaration of store looks like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  myPigeons: pigeonReducer,
  myBadges: badgesReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
```

I know that I could in theory now apply something like that to my store directly underneath:

```
store.subsribe(state => console.log(state));
```

and every time the store would change his state, it would be shown in my console.
The problem I face through is that I want to subscibe to the store, just not in the same js file.

What I want to accomplish is to listen to store changes in the entire app, somewhere in a navigator child component and automaticly detect when the store changes.

Going in detail, I am using firebase listeners within one of my screens. As soon as I want to change the user in my app (thats where I reset my whole redux store, thats why I want a redux store listener) the firebase listeners dont stop because I need to stop them in the same js file I initialized them, and therefore I will need to implement the redux store listener inside the exact same file, **which is NOT the same file in which I created my redux store.** I need to listen to redux changes inside my chatscreen and as soon as I change user I need to register that redux store is empty and call my firebase listeners to stop.

Do you think this is possible and if yes, how I could do that?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but is your problem not being able to use the store.subscribe () function on a different pages?

Comment: Why are you not using react-redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is caused by this, an approach can be made.

**On the page created in the Store:**

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
```

**On the page to be used in the Store:**

```
import {store} from '....'

store.subscribe (() => {
    // You can choose your reducers
    let {auth, myPigeons} = store.getState();
    console.log(auth);

    // Brings up the whole store
    let state = store.getState();
    console.log(state);
});
```

So you can subscribe to your store on any page. However, try to avoid the memory leak when using subscriber events. When you're done, cancel your subscription.

Comment: Tried it out, works perfectly. Only thing I miss is canceling the subscription as soon as store changes, I need to try out if its possible to cancel the listener within itself so basicly self destroy if it detects any change.